# Matrices nxn con numeros reales

Tags: c++, matrices, dev-c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
```

Están son las librerías que estoy usando, si alguna está de más díganme

```
using namespace std;
```

Aquí declaro mi constante TAMAÑO 5, pero necesito preguntar al usuario un valor (n) para que mi matriz sea nxn

```
const int MAX = 5;


bool verifica(int ma[][MAX], int n){
    for(int f = 0; f < MAX; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < MAX; c++){
             if(ma[f][c] == n){
                return false;
             }
        }
    }
return true;
 }
```

Bool lo estoy utilizando para que no se repita ningún numero en la matriz.

```
int main(){
    int mat[MAX][MAX];
    int numero;
    srand(time(0));

    for(int f = 0; f < MAX; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < MAX; c++){
             numero = 1 + rand() % 30;
             while(!verifica(mat, numero)){
                numero = 1 + rand() % 25;
             }
             mat[f][c] = numero;
        }
    }

    for(int f = 0; f < MAX; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < MAX; c++){
             cout<<setw(3)<<mat[f][c]<<" ";
        }cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Necesito solicitar un valor entero n para determinar el tamaño de matriz a utilizar como ya había escrito arriba , con un mínimo de 3 y un máximo de 10, luego se debe rellenar las dos matrices de tamaño n x n con valores aleatorios de tipo real comprendidos en el rango entre -100.00 y 100.00 aquí lo que he hecho es solo mostrar una sola matriz con números enteros no encuentro la manera de ponerlos en reales y con dos decimales solamente.

Answer (score 0):

> Necesito solicitar un valor entero n para determinar el tamaño de matriz a utilizar.

Ninguna de las soluciones que propones cumplen con el requisito. Dado que estás programando en C++ te aconsejo usar los contenedores estándar, el más adecuado para tu propósito es `std::vector`:

```
using Fila = std::vector<double>;
using Matriz = std::vector<Fila>;

int tamanyo = 0;
std::cin >> tamanyo;

Matriz mat(tamanyo, Fila(tamanyo));
```

Fíjate que he usado `double` como tipo de las filas de la matriz en lugar de `int`, ya que parece que ese es tu requerimiento.

Para rellenar los números aleatorios, las funciones de generación de números que estás usando (`rand`) pertenecen a C, en C++ deberías usar [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

```
std::random_device rd;                             // Generador de números.
std::mt19937 gen(rd());                            // Usará mersenne twister.
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-100., 100.); // La distribución será uniforme entre -100 y 100

for (auto &f : mat)   // Recorremos las filas de 'mat'.
    for (auto &v : f) // Recorremos los valores de la fila.
        v = dis(gen); // Asignamos un número aleatorio de la distribución.
```

Para imprimir con dos decimales, usa `std::fixed` y `std::setprecision`:

```
for (const auto &f : mat)   // Recorremos las filas de 'mat'.
{
    for (const auto &v : f) // Recorremos los valores de la fila.
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << v << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

No te preocupes por las repeticiones de valores, en una distribución normal de números reales difícilmente tendrás repetición alguna. Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JCiDwCQiAlaH88qB).